# When to use most things and when to use most of (the) things

Tags: prepositions, articles

I want to know when we should use "of" after "most." For instance,

> *Most **of the** documents* are read completely.

Or

> *Most documents* are read completely.
>
> *Most **of (the)** people* know about that.

Or

> *Most people* know about that.

What is the general rule?

Comment: The general rule is that if you include the (optional) definite article ***the***, you're *explicitly* referring to some particular documents or group of people - the documents we were talking about earlier, or "the people" identified as a substantial part of "society in general", for example.

Answer (score 3):

When you say *most people* or *most books* you are speaking in general terms about the majority of people (in a country, in the world) and the majority of books (eg. are soft-back or are now available online).

> > Most people would agree with me .....
> >
> > Most people would object to your views...

When you speak of *most of the people* you are talking about people in a particular context and not universally:

> > Most of the people in the hall....
> >
> > Most of the people who went to university...

The same applies to books:

> > Most of the books in the library....
> >
> > Most of the books that I have read...

Thus *most of the documents* would refer to specific documents

*Most documents* would refer to documents in general.

Answer (score 3):

It's a difference of scope. Adding "of the" narrows the scope. For instance:

> Most people know about that.

This implies that most people in the world know about "that".

> Most of the people know about that.

This implies that most people *in the group being referenced* know about "that".

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in practice *most of the people know that* would often be used in contexts where there isn't actually any specific "group being referenced". The implication in that case is usually that the conversants don't really consider *themselves* to be included in "the people" - for example, a couple of political spin doctors talking about whether the ordinary (voting) public are aware of something.